# Implemenation of service in Symbian

Tags: symbian

In transient server implementation, the client application is a console-based exe.

I want to know if I can integrate my GUI-based appplication with client and server given in transient server.

What is the best way?

1. Whether it is good to convert client exe to dll and use the dll in my application using RLibrary.
2. Whether it is good to implement LIB and integrate this into the project.

Right now I am able to launch TestClient.exe from my GUI application using startup api.

If I want to run the server in the backround and my GUI application in the foreground, what is the best way to integrate transient server with GUI application?

Launching TextClient.exe will not solve my problem because I want to communicate my GUI communicate with client

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to separate the GUI from a daemon-like background process, you might want to check out the concept of client/server architecture on symbian - not to be confused with client/server networking situations.

Symbian Client/Server architecture allows two-way communication between the GUI in your example and the background process.

[Forum Nokia - Introduction to the client-server architecture](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Base-subsystem-guide/e32/InterProcessCommunication/ClientServer/ClientServerIntroduction.guide.html#ClientServerGuide%2eclient%2dserver%2eclient%2dserver)

Comment: hi,

i have implemented client server architecture

but my problem is that,tcp ip socket taking time to read data from socket and i am getting response from client in service method

in that service method i have to write responce to client which 


how to implement tcp socket in symbian

Comment: Communication from client to server in Symbian architecture is asynchronous. The client watches the TRequestStatus that is associated with the message it has sent to the server. When the server completes the RMessage, ActiveScheduler calls the RunL method on the client side. 

So, you can do your TCP communication on the server side first, parse the incoming data, and then only after the data was received you can complete the RMessage.

Comment: thanks for reply

code i am having for client -server implementation is taken from file server example which dont have active object RunL() and asychronous call it only having connect() and start server() method

during write operation if i provide TRequeststatus parameter it crashes with user panic 70(stray signal)

can u provide me link of any example which have implemented proper client and any sample code

Comment: With some googling, on http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=125929 I found, there is on in the SDK: \Symbian\9.1\S60_3rd\Examples\Base\IPC\ClientServer\ and one online http://www.meme-education.com/ASDBookSOSEcode.html

Comment: thanks for reply
i am able to implement asychronous cleint server architecture
my problem is that ,there is tcp socket which i integrate in server which is derive from (CServer2)class CTimeServer : public CServer2 which is also active object to get value to chat socket if i call 
CTimeServer* iTimeServer = CTimeServer::NewL();        
iTimeServer->SendTimeToSessions(data);
delete iTimeServer;
it crahses with user panic 47 b'coz in constructL() of  CTimeServer


how to resolve conflict of two active

Comment: You can only watch one TRequestStatus per ActiveObject. If you need to watch multiple TRequestStatus' in sequence, you need to have separate AO's for that and something like a state machine implementation controlling them, otherwise you easily get stray signal panics.